# What does the complete.cases() code do for the dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

I ran a summary of my data in R and got top results for my data and then I ran complete.cases(df) and reran another summary and the content in my top results changed. What does the complete.cases(df) do to your dataset?

Answer (score 3):

?complete.cases() shows the documentation and gives you all the information you need:

It returns a logical vector which specifies which rows have no missing values (NAs).

so `df[complete.cases(df),]` removes all rows containing NA's. This means it also removes values in other columns thus changing the output of summary().

Answer (score 0):

`complete.cases` will inform you whether there are any missing values (`NA`) in each row of a vector, data frame, or matrix.

For example for a vector

```
vec = c(1:3, NA, 5:7, NA, NA, 10)
> vec
[1]  1  2  3 NA  5  6  7 NA NA 10
# Notice NA values in the 4th, 8th and 9th position corresponding to NA's in the 4th, 8th and 9th position

> complete.cases(vec)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# We have a FALSE in the 4th, 8th and 9th position
```

In the case of a data frame, consider

```
col.a = c(275, 250, 300, 290)
col.b = c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta")
col.c = c(2,3,1,1)

df = data.frame(col.a, col.b, col.c)
> df
col.a   col.b col.c
1   275   alpha     2
2   250   bravo     3
3   300 charlie     1
4   290   delta     1

#df of 4 rows currently does not have any NA

> complete.cases(df)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

#Let's introduce some NA's
col.a = c(NA, 250, 300, 290)
col.b = c("alpha", "bravo", NA, "delta")
col.c = c(2,3,NA,1)

df = data.frame(col.a, col.b, col.c)
> df
  col.a col.b col.c
1    NA alpha     2
2   250 bravo     3
3   300  <NA>    NA
4   290 delta     1

#There are NA's in row 1 and 3
> > complete.cases(df)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE

# We have a FALSE in the 1st and 3rd position, corresponding to NA's in the 1st and 4th row
```